# Contact Builder API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, contactbuilder

Are there any API for interacting with Contact Builder (i.e. Defining the Contact Model)?

I have gone through documentation and can only find creating contacts.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through this documentation:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm

Which is the REST reference to most of Marketing Cloud API's it includes the endpoints for interaction with Contact Builder API and of course examples on how to send HTTP calls to that endpoints.

Answer (score -1):

I strongly recommand to use this Postman collection : https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/postman

You have many routes to interact with Contact Builder API.

Comment: I use the Postman collection but it seems to only provide a subject (eg. Contacts update, delete), and not setting cardinality for objects or data attributes

Comment: Although a great resource, this does not answer his question.